How to reset a WebElement value to null without inserting a space after using the clear() method in Selenium WebDriver?
I'm currently working on test automation using Selenium WebDriver, and I encountered an issue while trying to reset the value of a WebElement to null. Here's a snippet of my code:
WebElement EditName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//input[@class='form-control fw-bold'])[1]")));
EditName.clear();

I attempted to use the clear() method followed by sendKeys("") to reset the value, but this inserted a space instead of clearing the value completely. I want to ensure that there's no value, not even a space, after clearing the WebElement.
Is there a way to achieve this without inserting any characters into the field? Should inserting a space after using clear() be considered a bug, or is there a different approach I should be taking?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

You shouldn't need to insert a space or empty string (???) after using .clear(). Just use .clear(). But... every site is different and may behave strangely due to bugs, etc.
Other than .clear(), you could use CTRL+A then BACKSPACE to clear the text. Here's some code using an example page.
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

String url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
username.sendKeys("test");
username.clear();
username.sendKeys("test2");
username.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE));


I did it without inserting anything in the first, but it wouldn't do anything! The previous value still appears even with the clear() method

Are you sure you have the right INPUT? Have you tried using .sendKeys() on the same element and confirmed that the text appears?

yes i'm sure , and i have tried it

Is it ok to share the website link to check? @HADEELهديل

@HADEELهديل I've updated my answer with another option.

i can't actually my apologize –
Anand Gautam
